# $a_{-1}$ term of a function on the punctured plane?

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

Our instructor said if f is analytic on the punctured complex plane (missing origin), then $$a_{-1}=\oint_{|z|=r} f(z) dz$$ This may be an obvious question, but what happened to the $\frac{1}{2\pi i}$ term before the integral?

Comment: I checked with the example in the book, and when $f$ is restricted to $D=C \setminus \{ 0 \}$, it also says this is valid.

Comment: The factor should be there. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_(complex_analysis)#Calculating_residues).

Comment: This is the word for word hint for an exercise: Let $f(z)=\sum{a_n z^n}$. Then $a_{-1}=\int_{|z|=r}f(z)dz$. (Where f is analytic on $D=C\setminus\{0\}$)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a mistake. Good job for noticing it!